Set default selected font size in Quill editor
I'm trying to programmatically set the default font size for different Quill rte's on a page in my application, but each approach seems more and more of a hacky workaround than something that would seem pretty straightforward.
I'm using Quill (ngx-quill ^25.3.2/quill ^2.0.0) in my Angular v17 application and I've tried using Angular's various if statement syntax for the selected attribute on the <option> tag that I need to set as the default font size, but I've run into many dead ends with that approach.
The one thing I've gotten to work, though seemingly through hoops and ladders, is getting the correct font size to be selected in the dropdown. Here's the approach I've gotten to work:
export class QuillEditor implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("contextModel", { static: true }) contextModel: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("toolbar", { static: true }) toolbarElement: ElementRef;
  @Input() isHeaderOrFooter = false;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeQuill()
  }

  private initializeQuill(): void {
    const editorElement = this.contextModel.nativeElement;
    const toolbarElement = this.toolbarElement.nativeElement;

    let fontSizeStyle = Quill.import("attributors/style/size");
    fontSizeStyle.whitelist = // array of px font sizes;
    Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);
    this.Quill = new Quill(editorElement, {
            theme: "snow",
            modules: {
                table: true,
                toolbar: toolbarElement,
            },
            placeholder: "Enter Text",
    });
    // other quill setup
    const defaultFontSize = this.isHeaderOrFooter ? "10px" : "14px";
    // this seems pretty hacky, but it works
    const quillLength = this.Quill.getLength();
    this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize);
    const sizeDropdown = toolbarElement.querySelector("select.ql-size");
    if (sizeDropdown) {
        sizeDropdown.value = defaultFontSize; // Set default font size in dropdown
        sizeDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
     }
  }
}

The only thing I can't seem to get working is having the editor font size to reflect the default selected font size. Any guidance would be much appreciated

To make the default font size work in both the Quill editor and the dropdown, you'll want to ensure a few things:
Properly Apply the Font Size to the Editor's Content: You need to ensure the font size is applied to the editor's content in a consistent manner, so both the content and the dropdown show the same value.
Set the Dropdown Correctly: It's great that you're setting the dropdown's value, but there needs to be a proper way to set the font size to the editor's content based on that dropdown value.
Here’s how you can achieve both goals:

Set the Default Font Size in the Quill Editor:
Instead of just using formatText to set the default font size after initializing Quill, you can also use Quill's default configuration and editor API to set the font size right from the start. When initializing the editor, make sure to set the default format for the content.
private initializeQuill(): void {
const editorElement = this.contextModel.nativeElement;
const toolbarElement = this.toolbarElement.nativeElement;
// Register custom font size whitelist (optional)
let fontSizeStyle = Quill.import("attributors/style/size");
fontSizeStyle.whitelist = ["10px", "12px", "14px", "16px", "18px", "20px"];  // Customize as needed
Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);
// Initialize Quill editor
this.Quill = new Quill(editorElement, {
theme: "snow",
modules: {
table: true,
toolbar: toolbarElement,
},
placeholder: "Enter Text",
formats: ["size"],  // Ensure 'size' is a valid format
});
// Determine default font size based on input or condition
const defaultFontSize = this.isHeaderOrFooter ? "10px" : "14px";
// Set default font size for editor content
const quillLength = this.Quill.getLength();
this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize);
// Set font size in the toolbar dropdown
const sizeDropdown = toolbarElement.querySelector("select.ql-size");
if (sizeDropdown) {
sizeDropdown.value = defaultFontSize;
sizeDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
}

Setting Font Size in Quill’s formatText:
The line this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize); applies the font size to the content in the editor. If this is not reflecting, it might be because you're applying it after Quill is initialized, but Quill might not have fully rendered the content yet.


To ensure this works properly, you can delay the application of the font size until Quill is fully initialized:
private initializeQuill(): void {
  const editorElement = this.contextModel.nativeElement;
  const toolbarElement = this.toolbarElement.nativeElement;

  let fontSizeStyle = Quill.import("attributors/style/size");
  fontSizeStyle.whitelist = ["10px", "12px", "14px", "16px", "18px", "20px"];
  Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);

  this.Quill = new Quill(editorElement, {
    theme: "snow",
    modules: {
      table: true,
      toolbar: toolbarElement,
    },
    placeholder: "Enter Text",
    formats: ["size"],
  });

  // Use setTimeout to apply font size after the editor is fully initialized
  setTimeout(() => {
    const defaultFontSize = this.isHeaderOrFooter ? "10px" : "14px";
    const quillLength = this.Quill.getLength();
    this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize);

    const sizeDropdown = toolbarElement.querySelector("select.ql-size");
    if (sizeDropdown) {
      sizeDropdown.value = defaultFontSize;
      sizeDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    }
  }, 0);
}


Make Sure Toolbar and Editor Sync Properly:
Sometimes, there can be a mismatch between the toolbar selection and the editor’s applied styles if Quill doesn't refresh its internal state properly. You can manually trigger a refresh after applying the font size:
setTimeout(() => {
const defaultFontSize = this.isHeaderOrFooter ? "10px" : "14px";
const quillLength = this.Quill.getLength();
this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize);
const sizeDropdown = toolbarElement.querySelector("select.ql-size");
if (sizeDropdown) {
sizeDropdown.value = defaultFontSize;
sizeDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
// Manually trigger Quill’s internal state update to sync the toolbar and editor
this.Quill.root.style.fontSize = defaultFontSize;
}, 0);


4.Handle Multiple Editors:
If you have multiple instances of Quill on the page (e.g., different editors with different configurations), you can use a similar approach for each one by managing the defaultFontSize and ensuring that both the editor content and toolbar are synchronized. You can use @ViewChild or pass configurations as inputs to handle this dynamically
The key here is applying the font size in a way that both the content inside the Quill editor and the dropdown toolbar reflect the same value. Using setTimeout ensures that you’re waiting until Quill is fully initialized before applying the styles and triggering the dropdown change event. You should also ensure that any font size applied to the editor is correctly reflected in the toolbar by manually setting the dropdown value and dispatching the change event.

This is something I also tried, but did not work

Quill is fully initialized before setting the font size.
Both the toolbar dropdown and the editor content reflect the desired default font size.
Updates to Quill’s internal state are properly synchronized.
export class QuillEditor implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("contextModel", { static: true }) contextModel: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("toolbar", { static: true }) toolbarElement: ElementRef;
  @Input() isHeaderOrFooter = false;
  private Quill;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeQuill();
  }

  private initializeQuill(): void {
    const editorElement = this.contextModel.nativeElement;
    const toolbarElement = this.toolbarElement.nativeElement;

    // Register custom font size whitelist if needed
    const fontSizeStyle = Quill.import("attributors/style/size");
    fontSizeStyle.whitelist = ["10px", "12px", "14px", "16px", "18px", "20px"]; // Customize as needed
    Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);

    // Initialize Quill editor
    this.Quill = new Quill(editorElement, {
      theme: "snow",
      modules: {
        table: true,
        toolbar: toolbarElement,
      },
      placeholder: "Enter Text",
      formats: ["size"], // Include size in the formats
    });

    // Set the default font size
    const defaultFontSize = this.isHeaderOrFooter ? "10px" : "14px";
    this.applyDefaultFontSize(defaultFontSize, toolbarElement);
  }

  private applyDefaultFontSize(defaultFontSize: string, toolbarElement: HTMLElement): void {
    // Delay to ensure Quill is fully initialized
    setTimeout(() => {
      const quillLength = this.Quill.getLength();
      
      // Apply default font size to the editor's content
      this.Quill.formatText(0, quillLength, 'size', defaultFontSize);
      
      // Directly set the font size on the root element
      this.Quill.root.style.fontSize = defaultFontSize;

      // Update the toolbar dropdown value
      const sizeDropdown = toolbarElement.querySelector("select.ql-size");
      if (sizeDropdown) {
        sizeDropdown.value = defaultFontSize;
        sizeDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); // Sync toolbar dropdown
      }

      // Force Quill to update, re-rendering with the new style
      this.Quill.update();
    }, 0);
  }
}

Key Improvements
setTimeout: Ensures the font size settings apply after Quill’s internal state is ready.
Explicitly setting this.Quill.root.style.fontSize: Applies the default font size to the editor root, covering any missed elements.
Synchronizing the toolbar: Updates the toolbar dropdown to reflect the chosen default font size.
this.Quill.update(): Forces Quill to refresh the content and toolbar, applying the new font size consistently.
Additional Debugging Tips
Check DOM in DevTools: Inspect the .ql-editor and the font size in the select.ql-size dropdown to confirm the applied styles.
Console Logs: Add console.log statements to verify each stage of initialization if it’s still not syncing as expected.

sorry, but that also does not resolve the issue
